Como identificar los datos null entregados en un metodo
Cordial saludo. Desarrollando un metodo para incluir dos campos a una tabla, campos que nos permitiran hacer controles internos, estas obteniendo un error que no permite que avancemos. El metodo es el siguiente:
[HttpGet("/Llantas/Mantenimientos/Obras", Name = "GetLlantasMantenimientosAgregarObras")]
    public List<TemGeneMttoPrevObras> GetLlantasMantenimientosAgregarObras(int Anhos, int Mes)
    {
        try
        {
            var q = from a in context.GeneMttoPrev
                    // 2024-06-20: Join entre dos tablas (tabla a y tabla b1).
                    join b1 in context.GeneAlmacenObra on
                            a.bodega
                        equals
                            b1.Bodega
                        into GrupoB
                    // 2024-06-20: Esto lo hago para que que sean LEFT JOIN.
                    from b in GrupoB.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    // 2024-06-20: Join entre dos tablas (tabla a y tabla c1)
                    join c1 in context.LlanHistoria on new
                    {
                        Equipo = a.equipo,
                        Fecha = a.fecha_mantenimiento
                    }
                    equals new
                    {
                        Equipo = c1.equipo,
                        Fecha = c1.Fecha!
                    }
                    into GrupoC
                    // 2024-06-20: Esto lo hago para que que sean LEFT JOIN.
                    from c in GrupoC.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    where
                        a.fecha_mantenimiento.Year == Anhos
                        &&
                        (
                            Mes == 0
                            ||
                            Mes == a.fecha_mantenimiento.Month
                        )
                    select new TemGeneMttoPrevObras
                    {
                        Registro = a.Registro,
                        equipo = a.equipo,
                        bodega = a.bodega,
                        codigo_mantenimiento = a.codigo_mantenimiento,
                        ciclo = a.ciclo,
                        frecuencia_Mantenimiento = a.frecuencia_Mantenimiento,
                        unidad_frecuencia = a.unidad_frecuencia,
                        fecha_estimada = a.fecha_estimada,
                        fecha_mantenimiento = a.fecha_mantenimiento,
                        horometro_estimado = a.horometro_estimado,
                        horometro_mantenimiento = a.horometro_mantenimiento,
                        horometro_final = a.horometro_final,
                        resultado_muestreo = a.resultado_muestreo,
                        emp = a.emp,
                        FechaInsert = a.FechaInsert,
                        // 2024-06-21: Se agrega el nombre de la obra de la tabla indicada.
                        Obra = b.Obra,
                        // 2024-06-21: Se valida si hay registros en la tabla indicada.
                        Estado = c == null ? "Pendiente" : "Insertada"
                    };
            // 2024-06-24: Se ordenan dos campos.
            return q.OrderBy(a => a.Obra).ThenBy(a => a.Estado).ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {           
            return TemGeneMttoPrevObrasExcepcion;
        }
    }

Al ejecutar el metodo, notoamos que se va al catch, ya que se esta presentando un error dentro del bloque Try. Con el animo de identificar a que se debe dicho error, procedemos a realizar debug al codigo encontrando el siguiente error:
System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: 'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.'

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]
AnalistaFlotasWAPIL.Controllers.LlantasController.GetLlantasMantenimientosAgregarObras(int, int) in LlantasController.cs

Como este error nos muestra un problema con datos null, procedemos a tratar de identficar donde se estan presentando dichos datos. Lo primero que hacemos es comentar el campo Obra = b.Obra, ya que consideramos que al hacer el join y no encontrar coincidencias se puede presentar los valores null. Luego de comentar dicho campo, procedemos nuevamente a realizar debug, pero a pesar de ello, se sigue presentando el mismo error.
De esta forma descomentamos Obra = b.Obra, y procedemos a comentar el otro campo que involucra un join, el cual es Estado = c == null ? "Pendiente" : "Insertada", procedemos a ralizar debug y encontramos que nuevamente se presenta el mismo error de datos null.
De esta forma, podemos decir que los datos que nos parecian ser los del problema, no tienen que ver con el error.
Lo otro que intentamos hacer, es ver todos los datos que nos entrega el objeto q, para poder identificar los valores null, esto lo hacemos realizando debug y antes de saltar al catch, precisamente cuando estamos en la linea return q.OrderBy(a => a.Obra).ThenBy(a => a.Estado).ToList(); tratamos de ver el contenido de q por medio de la opcion Watch. Al tratar de validar los datos contenidos en q en la opcion ResultView, nos dice que esta empty.
En este punto, ya no sabemos que mas hacer para lograr identificar el causante del error.
Para complementar la pregunta, agragamos las estructuras de las tablas utilizadas:
public class GeneMttoPrev
{
    [Key]
    // 2024-04-02: De esta forma, le informa al sistema que el campo es de tipo IDENTYTI, algo muy importante para
    // evitar errores que indican ingresos de datos explicitos a un campo tipo IDENTYTI.
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Registro { get; set; }
    public string? equipo { get; set; }
    public int bodega { get; set; }
    public string? codigo_mantenimiento { get; set; }
    public int ciclo { get; set; }
    public int frecuencia_Mantenimiento { get; set; }
    public string? unidad_frecuencia { get; set; }
    public DateTime fecha_estimada { get; set; }
    public DateTime fecha_mantenimiento { get; set; }
    public int horometro_estimado { get; set; }
    public int horometro_mantenimiento { get; set; }
    public int horometro_final { get; set; }
    public string? resultado_muestreo { get; set; }
    public string? emp { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaInsert { get; set; }
}

public class LlanHistoria
{
    // 2024-04-02: De esta forma, le informa al sistema que el campo es de tipo IDENTYTI, algo muy importante para
    // evitar errores que indican ingresos de datos explicitos a un campo tipo IDENTYTI.
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Registro { get; set; }
    public string? id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public string? equipo { get; set; }
    public int Ubicacion { get; set; }
    public decimal Horometro { get; set; }
    public decimal Odometro { get; set; }
    public string? operacion { get; set; }
    public decimal prof_1 { get; set; }
    public decimal prof_2 { get; set; }
    public decimal prof_3 { get; set; }
    public decimal presion { get; set; }
    public int salida { get; set; }
    public string? estado { get; set; }
    public string? situacion { get; set; }
    public string? observaciones { get; set; }
    public int bodega { get; set; }
    public string? usuario { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaIngreso { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaInsert { get; set; }
} 


public class GeneAlmacenObra
{
    [Key]
    // 2024-04-02: De esta forma, le informa al sistema que el campo es de tipo IDENTYTI, algo muy importante para
    // evitar errores que indican ingresos de datos explicitos a un campo tipo IDENTYTI.
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Registro { get; set; }
    public int Bodega { get; set; }
    public string? Almacen { get; set; }
    public string? Obra { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaInsert { get; set; }
}

Agradecemos sus indicaciones para poder continuar.

Para poder ayudarte mejor seria bueno si puedes agregar a tu pregunta, para completarla con "datos" de como es la estructura de la tablas (GeneMttoPrev, GeneAlmacenObra, LlanHistoria). Asi podremos ver cual cual puede ser nulleable (serguramente alguno que realizas los "order by" no creo que "inner join"). Y si puedes mejor... hacer consultas a la DB con un ejemplo de año/mes para ver los resultados (o sea lo mismo aqui con LINQ pero directo a la DB)

Me parece que tienes un problema en el modelo de C# que no coincide con el de la base de datos, también puede ser un problema de configuración en dbcontext. Además, he visto varias de tus preguntas y creo que tu modelo es no es el indicado, lo que provoca que tus consultas Linq sea más complejas de lo necesario. Es muy extraño realizas left join en linq, porque cuando tienes bien las propiedades de navegación simplemente el left join se hace a través de esas propiedades, con lo cual las consultas son sumamente sencillas.

Jose A. Fernandez, agradecemos su respuesta. En la pregunta incluimos la estructura de las tablas.

Yussef muchas gracias por sus indicaciones. Me gusta mucho trabajar con LinQ porque de esta forma no haga procedimientos almacenadas (sp) en la base de datos SQL Server sino que me encargo solo de hacer metodos en C#. De esa forma la logica del negocio la tengo aqui y la base de datos la uso para almacenar registros. Mi deseo es continuar aprendiendo LinQ. Usamos Left Join porque la intencion es que si un dato no esta en la tabla de busqueda, pueda aparecer como null, luego a ese null lo reemplazamos por otra palabra como "insertada" o "sin insertar". Gracias por sus recomendaciones.

German, creo que no entendiste lo que te señalé. Las propiedades de navegación te permiten hacer left join simples. Te mueves de una entidad a otra a través de su relación. Te sugiero que investigues sobre ello, tus consultas serán más simples

Listo Yussef, me pondre en ello. Muchas gracias.

Cordial saludo, primero agradeces a Jose A. Fernandes y a Yussef que con sus comentarios me ayudaron a exploerar nuevas alternativas.
Lo primero que buscamos fue identificar cual era el campo que nos estaba entregando valores nulos (null). Desde Visial Studio no fue sencillo identificarlo, por lo cual recurrimos a otra herramienta denominada LINQPad 7, con la cual podemos ejecutar expresiones como si estuvieramos en SQL Server y de esa forma obtener tablas con datos. Escribimos la consulta asi:
from a in GeneMttoPrev
// 2024-06-20: Join entre dos tablas (tabla a y tabla b1).
join b1 in GeneAlmacenObra on
        a.bodega
    equals
        b1.Bodega
    into GrupoB
// 2024-06-20: Esto lo hago para que que sean LEFT JOIN.
from b in GrupoB.DefaultIfEmpty()
// 2024-06-20: Join entre dos tablas (tabla a y tabla c1)
join c1 in LlanHistoria on new
{
    Equipo = a.equipo,
    Fecha = a.fecha_mantenimiento
}
equals new
{
    Equipo = c1.equipo,
    Fecha = c1.Fecha!
}
into GrupoC
// 2024-06-20: Esto lo hago para que que sean LEFT JOIN.
from c in GrupoC.DefaultIfEmpty()
where
    a.fecha_mantenimiento.Year == 2024
    &&
    (
        a.fecha_mantenimiento.Month == 5
    )
select new 
{
    Registro = a.Registro,
    equipo = a.equipo,
    bodega = a.bodega,
    codigo_mantenimiento = a.codigo_mantenimiento,
    ciclo = a.ciclo,
    frecuencia_Mantenimiento = a.frecuencia_Mantenimiento,
    unidad_frecuencia = a.unidad_frecuencia,
    fecha_estimada = a.fecha_estimada,
    fecha_mantenimiento = a.fecha_mantenimiento,
    horometro_estimado = a.horometro_estimado,
    horometro_mantenimiento = a.horometro_mantenimiento,
    horometro_final = a.horometro_final,
    resultado_muestreo = a.resultado_muestreo,
    emp = a.emp,
    FechaInsert = a.FechaInsert,
    // 2024-06-21: Se agrega el nombre de la obra de la tabla indicada.
    Obra = b.Obra,
    // 2024-06-21: Se valida si hay registros en la tabla indicada.
    Estado = c == null ? "Pendiente" : "Insertada"
}

Luego ejecutamos la consulta y la tabla que nos genero, nos permitio ver que el campo FechaInsert entrega valores nulos, ya que en la tabla original (SQL Server) es permitido pero en la clase creada en C# no los es.
Como todo los valores de dicho campo son nulos, convertimos este en un dato tipo DateTime y de esa forma, se logro corregir el error asi:
FechaInsert = new DateTime(1900-01-01),

La herramienta LINQPad 7 es de mucho ayuda y nos permitio identificar con facilidad la novedad.
Esperamos se de ayuda.
